# How to One to One relation sqlite3 python

Tags: python, sqlite

[image]

This is the relation I want to create for my quiz app and im using python

Module:

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE Questions (
                         mod_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                         mod_name TEXT NOT NULL
             )""")
```

Question:

```
 c.execute("""CREATE TABLE Questions (
                                    quest_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                                    quest_name TEXT NOT NULL,
                                    mod_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                                    FOREIGN KEY (mod_id)
                                        REFERENCES Modules (mod_id)
                        )""")
```

Now Since the each feedback correspont to 1 question, how do i sort of create one to one relationship? should I do the same as I did for the question table? would this be handle automatically by sqlite3??
Appreciate all sort of help Thanks!!!

EDIT: Does my feedback table need to have a primary key?? I think no because when accesing the feeback table to delete or add data we just pass the question ID as the parameter to look that row up.

Comment: If a Question has only 1 Feedback why do you need the table Feedback? Define a  column Free_Text in the table Question.

Comment: Ill do that thanks